# Can anyone explain why this equation using the fundamental theorem of calculus works?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

\begin{align}
        \left| f(b)-f(a)\right|&=\left| \int_a^b \frac{df}{dx} dx\right|\\ \ \\
        &\leq\left| \int_a^b \left|\frac{df}{dx}\right|\ dx\right|.
\end{align}

I do not understand why the second line is greater or equal than the top equation. Can anyone explain please?

Comment: State the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: Did you try to make a picture of the situation? It may make everything much easier.

Comment: I am not sure how to draw a picture of the situation.

Comment: The fundamental theorem of calculus (connection of derivative and integral) has nothing with this inequality which just states that $|A+B|\le |A|+|B|$

Comment: Triangle inequality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\left|\displaystyle \int_a^b \dfrac{df}{dx} dx\right| \leq \displaystyle \int_a^b \left|\dfrac{df}{dx}\right|dx \leq \left|\displaystyle \int_a^b \left|\dfrac{df}{dx}\right|dx\right|$

Comment: Is your inequality correct for $f(x)=x$, $a=1$, $b=0$?

Answer (score 6):

Let $u$ be integrable (in your case it is $\frac{df}{dx}$).
Because $u(x)\le |u(x)|$ we have
$$\int_a^bu(x)\,\mathrm dx\le \int_a^b|u(x)|\,\mathrm dx $$
for $a\le b$. 
Because $-u(x)\le |u(x)|$ we have
$$-\int_a^bu(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_a^b(-u(x))\,\mathrm dx\le \int_a^b|u(x)|\,\mathrm dx $$
for $a\le b$. As $|y|=\max\{y,-y\}$, we conclude 
$$ \left|\int_a^bu(x)\,\mathrm dx\right|\le \int_a^b|u(x)|\,\mathrm dx $$
whenever $a\le b$. If we take absolute values on the right hand side, we also treat the case $b<a$ because $|\int_a^b|=\max\{\int_a^b,-\int_a^b\}=\max\{\int_a^b,\int_b^a\}$, i.e. we have
$$ \left|\int_a^bu(x)\,\mathrm dx\right|\le \left|\int_a^b|u(x)|\,\mathrm dx \right|$$
for *all* numbers $a,b\in\mathbb R$.